# Apache DBUtils: Standard way to handle different datatype returned from SQL (INT/NULL)?

Tags: java, sql, apache-commons-dbutils, dbutils

Is there a standard proper java code to properly handle the following datatype which the result may possible returned as integer or null? I'm using common-dbutils to perform query execution.

```
--MSSQL
QUERY ="select ID from Users where Name='test'" --ID= int type
QueryRunner run = new QueryRunner();
int results = run.query(connection,QUERY, new ScalarHandler<Integer>());
```

ID returned as INT if where condition met.

ID returned as NULL if where condition not met. (Throw exception since unable to cast into INT)

Any standard java datatype/way should I returned to handle these kind of different scenarios?

Comment: all sql dialects have a function similar to `IFNULL(x,-1)` so you don't need to check for `NULL`, only if the result is positive, which works with ID's of course, because they can't be negative

Comment: @nbk sry for confusing (ID returned as NULL), SQL Query should be return as "no data" (no row at all) instead of NULL. I don think isnull/ifnull will able to handle this kind of scenario...

Comment: no, both would do the trick but it  would return text and not a number, so you must handle that, which would not improve or make it easier that chekcn for NULL

Comment: Thank you. I managed to handle this scenario by casting resultset into Object, then use "instanceof" to differentiate returned datatype either INT or string or null...